# Read from a file after have written to it with fstream - always empty

Tags: c++, file, c++11, fstream, ostream

```
std::fstream file("filename", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
    if (file)
    {
        file << "Some text" << std::flush;
        std::string buffer;
        //file >> buffer;
        std::getline(file, buffer);
        std::cout << buffer;
    }
```

I need to write to a file and read from it. After the run I can see the file with the text created, but with this code with both option how to read the  `buffer` it is always empty. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Reset the read pointer with `seekg`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `seekg(0)` to set the position to start. When you wrote on the file it move the position to the end and for reading it you have to move to start.

```
std::fstream file("filename", std::fstream::in | std::fstream::out | std::fstream::trunc);
if (file)
{
    file << "Some text" << std::flush;
    std::string buffer;
    //file >> buffer;
    file.seekg(0);
    std::getline(file, buffer);
    std::cout << buffer;
}
```